# Is there analog for startsWith function for byte array dataframe column in spark (scala)?

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to read hbase table with hortonworks spark hbase connector. Key of this table has Binary type, and I want to filter data as same as hbase scan does. Key has this structure: [8 bytes of UserId, 8 bytes of Timestamp, 4 bytes some other data]. Is it possible to filter like this:

```
df.filter($"key".startsWith(Array(x,x,x,x,x)))
```

to find all rows, corresponded to particular UserId?

UPD:
Hortonworks connector is actually not important thing, you can get dataframe something like this:

```scala
val df = Seq(  
 java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(20).putLong(java.lang.Long.reverse(12345678L)).putLong(11111L).putInt(1234).array(),
 java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(20).putLong(java.lang.Long.reverse(87654321L)).putLong(222222L).putInt(2345).array(),
 java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(20).putLong(java.lang.Long.reverse(12345678L)).putLong(333333L).putInt(3456).array()
).toDF("key")
```

so output will be:

```
scala> df.show(false)
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|key                                                          |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|[72 86 3D 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 2B 67 00 00 04 D2]|
|[8D FE 9C A0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 64 0E 00 00 09 29]|
|[72 86 3D 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 05 16 15 00 00 0D 80]|
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Well I have not worked with hbase and hortonworks so far, but, if you can provide a string representation of keys that would help(i.e. by printing to the console, I want to know how the key is received), for instance, if the key is something like `"11010100101"`, you can probably do this `df.filter("key".startsWith(Array(x, x, x, x, x).mkString("")))`

Comment: @AminMal thanks for your reply, I updated question with more information

Comment: I don't know if this would work for you, but, you can convert that array of hexadecimal bytes into array of integers like `keyArray.map(hex => Integer.parseInt(hex, 16))` and then compare with your Array(x, x, x, x)